# Handle collection of mixed doubles and nulls in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Mongo document that, among other things, has an object that stores a list of doubles:

```
  id: ...,
  metrics : [
    {
      name: "miles/hr",
      values : [
         10.0,
         10.4,
         10.2,
         11.0
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I'm using Spring data to read these objects from the collection using the following Java object:

```
public class Performance {
   public String id;
   public List<Metric> metrics = new ArrayList();
}

public class Metric {
   public String name;
   public List<Double> values;
}
```

And the repository is pretty basic:

```
@Repository
public interface PerformanceRepository extends MongoRepository<Performance, String> {
   List<Performance> findByIdIn(Collection<String> ids);
}
```

My problem is that this data comes from an external data provider, and on some occasions I get a mix of doubles and nulls:

```
  id: xxx,
  metrics : [
    {
      name: "miles/hr",
      values : [
         10.0,
         null,
         null,
         11.0
      ]
    }
  ]
```

This causes null pointer exceptions in the Spring repository:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1885) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:1139) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$$Lambda$1773/000000000000000000.convert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1900) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1636) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:477) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:392) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:371) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:341) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
```

Is there a way to gracefully handle these documents, perhaps through an annotation on the metrics field or a custom query? Ideally I just want to convert the `null` entries to a default value like `0.0` rather than just discard them.

Comment: This seems to work as expected with current development _main_ line (3.4). Does the issue persist using `3.3.x`? If so please report an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues), ideally providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChristophStrobl This is actually back in spring data 2.2.3. Yikes. Let me see how painful the upgrade is and whether I can reproduce there. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristophStrobl I upgraded to 3.3.1 and I'm not seeing the problem anymore, thanks for the info!